# Simple C++ interface to concepts example

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I have an interface as follows:

```cpp
struct TestInterface 
{
    void on_read(unsigned len, const char* buf);
};
```

My attempt at expressing this as a concept is as follows:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept TestConcept = requires(T a)
{
    { a.on_read(unsigned, const char*) } -> void;
};
```

However, this does not compile. What is the correct syntax for this?

Errors I am getting are:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘unsigned’
error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
error: return-type-requirement is not a type-constraint
```

As a side question, is there a way to enforce public / private members when declaring concepts?

This question might be too basic, please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- you have to use the objects not the types in the parameter list of the method to check
- you have to check the type with SFINAE expression because the return type itself did not result in failure if it is different to the expected one.

```
struct TestInterface
{
    void on_read(unsigned len, const char* buf);
};

struct TestInterface2
{
    int on_read(unsigned len, const char* buf);
};

struct TestInterface3
{
    void on_read(unsigned len, const int* buf);
};

struct TestInterface4
{
    private:
    void on_read(unsigned len, const int* buf);
};

template<class T>
concept TestConcept = requires(T a)
{
    { a.on_read(unsigned{},std::declval<const char*>()) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << TestConcept<TestInterface> << std::endl;
    std::cout << TestConcept<TestInterface2> << std::endl;
    std::cout << TestConcept<TestInterface3> << std::endl;
    std::cout << TestConcept<TestInterface4> << std::endl;
}
```

The method must be public to get the concept be valid as the expression a.on_read() also checks that the method is accessible.

If someone have an idea how to check for a private function, would be nice to give me a hint :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, is there a public / private differentiation for the expressions defined int the concept? - Essentially I am asking how do I guarantee that the member requirements I state in the concept are all made public?

Comment: @tinkerbeast: Instead of "thanks" it would be nice to get the accept "payment" :-) BTW: It is not common to extend a question by comments. As your question to detect public vs private is a good one, you should simply post another question please.

Comment: accepted the answer. I am not extending the original question. The original question had the same question (see second last line).

Comment: @tinkerbeast: Oh yea! You are right... For the simple case: the method must be public to get the concept be valid as the expression `a.on_read()` also checks that the function is accessible. I currently have no idea how to check the existence a a private function... thats a real good question :-)

Comment: @tinkerbeast added that also to my answer

Comment: `template<class T>
concept TestConcept = requires(T a, unsigned u, const char* s)
{
    { a.on_read(u, str)) } -> std::same_as<void>;
};` is better imo.